# SQL Mirroring 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I have a mirror and witness setup with automatic failover setup. The server side of the mirroring works fine, when we take the network cable out the databases failover to the failover server.

The problem I have is that the connection string that I am using:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=WCFTEPATSQL01;Failover_Partner=WCFTEPATSQL02;Initial Database=DBForms;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;Network=dbmssocn;Pooling=false
```

is not sending the connection to the failover partner when the primary server is down. I can change the server address to the failover address and this will work but this is not what I should be doing.

The setup is classic asp on IIS 7.5.

Any help would be great as I have tried almost everything out there.

Comment: Noticed similar problem when developing for SSRS. Seems that once a connection is open, it stays pointed at the same server. Recycling the application pool seems to help, but you can't be doing that all day.

Comment: No I still get [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. after I recycle the AppPool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own issue, it looks like the SQL Server driver didn't recognise the Failover Partner, I changed the connection string to:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Failover_Partner=WCFTEPATSQL02;Server=WCFTEPATSQL01;Database=DBForms;Trusted_Connection=yes;Network=dbmssocn;Pooling=false
```

and all is good.